# Why can't I start Eclipse after I killed it once?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse IDE in my computer running Ubuntu 13.10 hung once. I just killed the process. Thereafter it shows this whenever I try to start Eclipse:

> Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob

The Eclipse splash occurs, but as soon as the progress bar fills up, no Eclipse window appears. The problem persists even after restart of computer.

Eclipse version: 4.3 with Android Plugin installed
Java version: jdk 1.8.0

Comment: Have you restarted since it crashed?

Comment: yes i did. actually this shows while i start the eclipse ide always even after restarting the pc.

Comment: Eclipse 4.8, how did that happen? The latest version of Eclipse from www.eclipse.org is Eclipse 4.4 Luna. In Ubuntu 13.10 the version of Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Center is Eclipse 3.8.

Comment: Now you are confusing me. What is your *actual* error and what is the *actual* version of Eclipse you are running?

Comment: actual error is the jobs part what are jobs and what unclosed jobs are there that is causing the problem and how to fix it. the version of eclipse is second last version 4.3. actually i cannot open eclipse so doing guessworks. since the latest is luna so mine is probably 2nd last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse creates a `.lock` file in the folder `.metadata` in your *Workspace* folder, e.g.:

```
~/workspace/.metadata
```

Remove the `.lock` file and Eclipse will start again

```
rm ~/workspace/.metadata/.lock
```